# Задать язык интерфейса на странице

Tags: c#, post, openstreetmap

Я пробую открыть карту openstreetmap в webbrowser с#. Карта открывается, но есть одна проблема. Сервер не может определить мой язык. Я искала различные способы исправить проблему и наткнулся на переопределение метода, где в **additionalHeaders**

```
public void Navigate(
   string urlString,
   string targetFrameName,
   byte[] postData,
   string additionalHeaders)
```

передается значение

> Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Но это мне не помогает. Язык как был английским так и остался. Возможно я что то делаю не так. Прошу хотя бы кокой нибудь подсказки.

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/1966/how-to-select-language-for-main-map-page/1977  ну, идея в принципе выглядит правильной, возможно стоит проверить разные комбинации для ru

Comment: Это вопрос я тоже видел. И да я пробовал различные варианты. Пробовал и этот испанский и немецкий, разве что китайский не пробовал, но сейчас попробую.

Comment: Ну, в браузере я сменить никак не смог, так что даже идей нет, как они там определяют. Говорят, в профиле сайта есть настройка для каждого, но вас такой вариант наверно ещё меньше устроит.